# Python Language Printing set() in my returned output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a function that will return the unique numbers of a list, in list form. For example:

```
l = [1,2,2,3,4]
```

My function would return: `[1,2,3,4]`

I used a set to do this, and my code is as follows:

```
def unique_list(l):
    se = set(l)
    lis = [se]
    return lis
print(unique_list(t))
```

And my output is: `[set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])]`

I would assume it has something to do with the `se = set(l)` or `lis = [se]` part of my code. However, I am learning by myself and am not exactly sure what could be causing this.

Comment: `def unique_list(l): return list(set(l))`. `[..]` does not create a list from the set's elements, it only encloses the the set object as a single element in a list (not the same thing).

Comment: Okay, so instead of saying `se = set(l)` I can just directly create a list by doing `return list(set(l))` ? Thanks, I never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the list incorrectly. Try something like this..

```
def unique_list(l):
    se = set(l)
    lis = list(se)
    return lis
print(unique_list(t))
```

Comment: I would even skip the `se = set(l)` and just do `lis = list(set(l))`

Comment: There is little need to use a function at all, could just use `list(set(l))` in line. However that isn't very helpful to explain why the code didn't work properly.

Comment: Well, it's good to know that but my 'assignment' from this video series was to make a function that does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [5,5,1,2,2,3,4]

def unique_list(l):
    se = set(l)  # get all the unique elements of list
    lis = list(se)  # convert set to list
    lis.sort(key=l.index)  # preserve order of original list
    return lis
print(unique_list(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(set(list_))` is fast for returning a list of *unordered* unique items.

`set(list_)` is sufficient for a unique collection if a list not critical.

Here are ways to remove replicates from a `list_` while preserving order:

```
import collections as ct


list(ct.OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_))
```

In Python 3.6+:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(list_))
```

See also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835527/4531270) by R. Hettinger and this [blog](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-way-to-uniquify-a-list-in-python-3.6) on *Fastest way to uniquify a list in Python >=3.6*